# Linking image without interface builder

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Recently I have ditched using storyboards and xibs in my app. While doing that it was quite easy linking images to the proper image name. Now I want to link them without those and running into trouble. Searched for quite some time on here and google without much success.

These images will be used for a after app launch splash screen to prevent the white flash, (worked perfect with IB). In my .h file I did this.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splash4InchPortrait;
```

How would I declare that image name from a image I have in my app say, splash4InchPortrait@2x.png ?

This is what I have in both files. Just to give you an idea of what I'm working with.

.h

```
@interface CenterViewController : UIViewController <PullToRefreshViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MTStatusBarOverlayDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *webView;
    NSTimer *timer;
    UIScrollView *currentScrollView;
    MTStatusBarOverlay *overlay;

}


@property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingMask;
@property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing bounds;


@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splash35InchPortrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splash35InchLandscape;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splashRetina35InchPortrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splashRetina35InchLandscape;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splash4InchPortrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splash4InchLandscape;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splashPadPortrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splashPadLandscape;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface UIViewController ()
@end

BOOL isPortraitView = YES;

@implementation CenterViewController

@synthesize splash35InchPortrait, splash35InchLandscape, splashRetina35InchPortrait, splashRetina35InchLandscape, splash4InchPortrait, splash4InchLandscape, splashPadPortrait, splashPadLandscape;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    [(UIWebView*)webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com"]]];

    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    for (UIView* subView in webView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            currentScrollView = (UIScrollView *)subView;
            currentScrollView.delegate = (id) self;

        }
    }
    webView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    webView.tag = 999;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);


//get screen size
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        //DO Portrait
        if (screenBounds.size.height <=480) {
            //code for 3.5-inch screen
            splash35InchPortrait.hidden = NO;
            splash35InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
            splashRetina35InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splash4InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
            splash4InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splashPadLandscape.hidden = YES;

        }else{
            // code for 3.5 Retina inch screen
            splash35InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = NO;
            splashRetina35InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splash4InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
            splashPadLandscape.hidden = YES;
        }

    }else{
        // code for 4-inch screen
        splash35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
        splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
        splash4InchPortrait.hidden = NO;
        splash4InchLandscape.hidden = YES;
        splashPadLandscape.hidden = YES;
    }



// Set up Pull to Refresh code
    PullToRefreshView *pull = [[PullToRefreshView alloc] initWithScrollView:currentScrollView];
    [pull setDelegate:self];
    pull.tag = 998;
    [currentScrollView addSubview:pull];

//Statusbar Overlay
    overlay = [MTStatusBarOverlay sharedInstance];
    overlay.delegate = self;
    overlay.progress = 0.0;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:1.0f];

// Forward / Back Gestures
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *goForward = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    goForward.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    goForward.delegate = self;
    goForward.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:goForward];    

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *goBack = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
    goBack.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    goBack.delegate = self;
    goBack.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:goBack];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return NO;
}


//Other Gestures
- (void)swipeLeftAction:(id)ignored{
    [webView goBack];
    [overlay postMessage:@"Go Back" duration:1 animated:YES];
}
- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored{
    [webView goForward];
    [overlay postMessage:@"Go Forward" duration:1 animated:YES];
}
-(void)pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh:(PullToRefreshView *)view {
    [(UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:999] reload];
    [overlay postMessage:@"Reloading" duration:1 animated:YES];
}



//Webview Start/Finish Request

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
#define IS_IPHONE (!IS_IPAD)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

    bool isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));
    if (isiPhone5) {
        // Loading iPhone 5
        [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }

    else if (IS_IPAD) {
        // Loading IPAD
        [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }

    else {
        // Loading iPhone 3.5"
        [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }

}


//Rotation
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"rotate(0)"];

    }
    else{
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"rotate(1)"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

//Image animation

- (void)tick {
    if (!webView.loading) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeimage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }
}

-(void)fadeimage{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    splash35InchPortrait.alpha = 0;
    splash35InchLandscape.alpha = 0;
    splashRetina35InchPortrait.alpha = 0;
    splashRetina35InchLandscape.alpha = 0;
    splash4InchPortrait.alpha = 0;
    splash4InchLandscape.alpha = 0;
    splashPadLandscape.alpha = 0;
    splashPadPortrait.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    webView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


@end
```

UPDATE:

With code merged from my old project and code from the accepted answer below (thanks kushyar). I managed to get it. If anybody is curious, this is what I did.

```
//Setting Splash Images
    #define IS_IPHONE (!IS_IPAD)
    #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

    bool isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));
    if (isiPhone5) {
        // Load iPhone 5 Splash
        UIImage *splash4Inch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
        self.splash4InchPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];
        [self.splash4InchPortrait setImage:splash4Inch];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splash4InchPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splash4InchPortrait];
        self.splash4InchPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }

    else if (IS_IPAD) {
        // Load IPAD StoryBoard
        UIImage *splashPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];
        self.splashPadPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 768.0f, 1024.0f)];
        [self.splashPadPortrait setImage:splashPad];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splashPadPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splashPadPortrait];
        self.splashPadPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }

    else {
        // Load the iPhone 3.5" Splash
        UIImage *splash35Inch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
        self.splash35InchPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
        [self.splash35InchPortrait setImage:splash35Inch];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splash35InchPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splash35InchPortrait];
        self.splash35InchPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the image as pointed out by @ggrana by first creating a `UIImage` and then setting the image property of `UIImageView` to that image.

so either

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash4InchPortrait"];
[splash4InchPortrait setImage:myImage];
```

or

```
[splash4InchPortrait setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash4InchPortrait"]];
```

You also have to initalize your UIImageView's inside the `- (void)loadView {}` method.

Make sure you set the frame of your `UIImageView` and also add them as a sub view of your `UIViewController` `view`.

One last note: You do not need to specify the `@2x` when you define your image as pointed above. The compiler does that for you based on the device it is running on.

EDIT: Ok try adding this to your implementation file.

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash4InchPortrait@2x.png"];
    self.splash4InchPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];
    [self.splash4InchPortrait setImage:myImage];
    [self.view addSubview:self.splash4InchPortrait];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splash4InchPortrait];



}
```

finally, make sure you release your image if you are not using ARC in the `dealloc` method.

```
- (void)dealloc {
      [self.splash4InchPortrait release]; 
}
```

this should get you started on a solid path.

Comment: Bare with me as I'm new to using just code. What specifically would I need to change in order to do that? Code provided above.

Comment: So in your implementation file (.m) you have the viewDidLoad method. You can either do it inside that or as I suggested, use the -(void)loadView {} method. I will modify my post for clarity. give me a minute.

Comment: No go, still not showing up. I'm only trying to get the Default-568h image to show for now. Thats what I'm using for my splash screen. As you see by the code I have a lot of other splash screens.

Comment: take note of the correct frame size, correct image name and also the bringSubviewToFront method.

Comment: @ChrisOSX did you try that?

Comment: Never worked how you had it, but taking your sample and merging it with older code I had, I managed to get it working. Posted code above. Will still accept this as a solution, because without it, it wouldn't have worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do the following:

- Create a custom view to encapsulate your components together.
- Your custom view can be *composed* of other custom views.

Then, rather than setting the hidden attribute on all of those components, you can define a single method that does this, and call it from the controller.

The spirit of the Model-View-Controller pattern is that the controller is a thin 'glue' layer between the model and view. Its purpose is to shunt/translate information back and forth between them.

**Loading Images**

NB: You only need to choose the image resource name - UIImage will choose the correct resource (@2x, 568h@2x, etc).

Regarding choosing the correct image to use: If you use the AppCode IDE from Jetbrains, you can do the following:

- Press Ctrl-space after typing [UIImage imageNamed:@""] to get a list of image files to choose from.
- ctrl-click on an image file-name to render it in the IDE and show the size, pixel depth, etc.

(You can probably also do this with Xcode - don't know, because its not my main IDE).